# lspci "Memory at..." vs /proc/bus/pci/devices BAR address

Tags: linux, bash, pci

I have a userspace application that I use to write to the registers of a pci device. It takes the base memory address of the device as an argument. Instead of looking this up via `lspci` on each platform, I wanted to write a bash script to use the vendor/device id's to look up the base address and call the application instead.

Lets use an Intel network controller with device ID of `0891' as example. This is on a Ubuntu box, but I need it to work across different Linux distributions.

I thought of just parsing the output of `lspci` with something like this:

```
lspci -vn | grep -A 3 0891 | grep Memory | awk '{print $3}'
```

which produces:

```
f0500000
```

But I'm interested in getting the base address from somewhere in the file system, rather than relying on another application, so I tried:

```
cat /proc/bus/pci/devices | grep 0891 | awk '{print $4}'
```

This produces:

```
f0500004
```

Why is the second value offset by 4 bytes?

Bonus question: Where can I get PCI device base memory addresses from that will work across distributions without relying on other applications such as lspci?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can determine the format of 0x????0004 communicates some additional information.  Bit 2 indicates that the BAR is a 1=64-bit, 0=32-bit address, bit 3 indicates that memory region is 1=prefetchable, 0=non-prefetchable.